# Why Crontab does not execute in the right minute

Tags: python, cron, python-requests, smtplib

I am setting up a crontab task that executes every 5 minutes on my ubuntu 18.04 server. This task (written with python3) should request some cryptocurrency price from cryptomarketcap.com and send email to me. However, the task does not execute as what I want.

I have checked the log of crontab and added logging command in my python code. But the result is very strange. It seems that in cron.log the task just executes in the perfect time

```
Apr 14 04:30:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[14979]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 04:35:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15004]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 04:39:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15088]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Apr 14 04:40:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15090]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 04:45:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15102]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 04:50:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15112]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 04:55:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15150]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
Apr 14 05:00:01 lemp-s-1vcpu-1gb-sgp1-01 CRON[15174]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh)
```

However, in the log recorded by python, things are quite different

```
start program  2019-04-14 04:30:01.932384
start request  2019-04-14 04:30:01.932869
end request  2019-04-14 04:30:02.690205
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:30:02.694734
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:30:06.602899
start program  2019-04-14 04:43:31.499914
start request  2019-04-14 04:43:31.500368
start program  2019-04-14 04:43:31.512064
start request  2019-04-14 04:43:31.514192
end request  2019-04-14 04:43:31.853871
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:43:31.859186
end request  2019-04-14 04:43:31.877854
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:43:31.881670
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:43:33.438788
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:43:33.477752
start program  2019-04-14 04:45:02.085442
start request  2019-04-14 04:45:02.085969
end request  2019-04-14 04:45:02.434488
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:45:02.439000
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:45:03.724816
start program  2019-04-14 04:50:02.236511
start request  2019-04-14 04:50:02.237008
end request  2019-04-14 04:50:02.938542
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:50:02.943317
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:50:04.690106
start program  2019-04-14 04:57:59.706844
start request  2019-04-14 04:57:59.707152
end request  2019-04-14 04:58:00.065410
start mailing  2019-04-14 04:58:00.069808
end mailing  2019-04-14 04:58:02.075729
start program  2019-04-14 05:00:01.557796
start request  2019-04-14 05:00:01.558173
end request  2019-04-14 05:00:02.180507
start mailing  2019-04-14 05:00:02.185072
end mailing  2019-04-14 05:00:03.440213
```

It can be seen that at 04:35 and 04:40 the program did not run,but at 04:43 it ran twice. Similar things at 04:57.

CODE:
The crontab command file

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /root/request_price/mail_price.sh
```

mail_price.sh

```
/root/anaconda3/bin/python3 /root/request_price/main.py
```

main.py

```py
import get_price as gp
from send_mail import send_mail
import json
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

with open('log.txt','a') as log:
    log.write('start program  '+str(datetime.now())+'\n')

raw_response = gp.request_api()

with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
    log.write('end request  ' + str(datetime.now()) + '\n')

status = raw_response['status']
time_utc = datetime.strptime(status['timestamp'][0:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
time_beijing = time_utc+timedelta(hours=8)

data = raw_response['data']
btc_price = gp.get_currency_price(data, 'BTC')
bch_price = gp.get_currency_price(data, 'BCH')

print(datetime.strftime(time_beijing, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

subject = 'Price'
content = 'BTC：'+"{0:.2f}".format(btc_price)+'\n BCH：'+"{0:.2f}".format(bch_price)+'\nTime：'\
    + datetime.strftime(time_beijing, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
receiver = "HIDE"

with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
    log.write('start mailing  ' + str(datetime.now()) + '\n')

send_mail(receiver, subject, content)

with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
    log.write('end mailing  ' + str(datetime.now()) + '\n')
```

get_price.py

```py
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json
from datetime import datetime


def request_api():
    url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
    parameters = {
        'start': '1',
        'limit': '100',
        'convert': 'USD',
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'HIDE',
    }

    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)

    with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
        log.write('start request  ' + str(datetime.now()) + '\n')

    try:
        response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        return data
    except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
        print(e)


def get_currency_price(data, symbol):
    for currency in data:
        if currency['symbol'] == symbol:
            return currency['quote']['USD']['price']
    return -1
```

send_mail.py

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr

def send_mail(receiver, subject, content):
    mail_host = "HIDE"
    mail_user = "HIDE"
    mail_pass = "HIDE"

    sender = 'HIDE'

    message = MIMEText(content, 'plain', 'utf-8')
    message['From'] = formataddr(["RapidSub Notification", sender]) 
    message['To'] = formataddr([receiver.split('@')[0], receiver])  

    message['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=mail_host)
        smtpObj.connect(mail_host, 465)   
        smtpObj.login(mail_user, mail_pass)
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
        print("Success")
        smtpObj.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print("Error: Fail")
        smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: First of all, cron does not guarantee execution exactly at the scheduled time https://serverfault.com/questions/721088/how-precise-is-a-cron-daemon

Comment: @AnthonyKong Thanks. But my "start program" logging command was just at the beginning of python code, so I guess this problem was not caused by the slowness of program.